# Feeds Setup to Automatically Update and Delete Nodes

Tags: feeds

I have an RSS feed from which I use Feeds module to fetch data from this to create nodes of a particular content type, I then use Views to display this information.

**What settings do I use to setup Feeds module to automatically keep the nodes created in sync with an RSS feed?**

This seams like it should be quite easy but I am coming across some trouble with this. The RSS feed has new items added, items updated and items deleted, so the feeds module need to look for all of these and be in sync with these changes.

These are my Settings:

- Attached to: None
- Use Standalone form
- Periodic import: Often as possible
- HTTP Fetcher
- XPath XML Parser
- Replace existing nodes
- Skip has check
- Expire nodes: after 1 day (this I set to delete nodes to keep in sync with items being removed)
- Elysia Cron is set to run update at 2am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Feeds are you using? Deletion of existing items is not currently in the latest stable release, but it is in the latest dev release of the Feeds module, 7.x-2.x-dev (2014-Sep-17).